# [<__NSCFString 0x600003802460> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key using FEMMApping Problem in mapping

Tags: ios, swift, mapping

I am using FEMMapping for mapping .I am getting this error :: 
[<__NSCFString 0x600003802460> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XYZ

```
 class func defaultmapping()->FEMMapping{
  mapping.addAttribute(Mapping.intAttributeFor(property: "XYZ", keyPath: "XYZ"))
}
 let objVisit = deserialiser.object(fromRepresentation: dicVisit, mapping: mapping)
print(objVisit)
```

getting error at line `let objVisit = ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode - How to fix 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/xcode-how-to-fix-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-valu)

Comment: No. I have problem in mapping .Its not coming while set any value

Comment: The error says you tried to set the property `XYZ` on an instance of `NSString`, so you haven't done something right...

Comment: but what may be issue it may happen that value is of different type and trying to set as integer ?

Comment: I have map other attribute in same way and its working